# How to find whether if user clicked spinner in Android?

Tags: android, spinner

In my application I am creating spinner dynamically in code.I want to force user to click on Spinner and change its value/content. Otherwise user should not be able to go to next screen by clicking Next button.

How to do that in Android? Anybody has any idea?

Thanks in Advance.

Rohan

Comment: simpally you just need to disable "Next" button until user change the value of spinner... is this simple required this much answers....????

Answer (score 9):

you can use this:

```
 if (spin.getSelectedItemPosition() < 0) {//Do something}
```

this means user hasn't selected anything.

Answer (score 2):

Let the Spinner's first value be something like "-please select-".

when the user clicks on the next button perform validation and check whether the value of the selectedItem in the spinner is "-please select-" and if yes, then display a toast and ask the the user to select something from the spinner.

you need code, let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Use this code for *checking* the **spinner item** is *selected or not*.

both flags take at class level (Globally).

```
Boolean temp = false;
Boolean check = false;


spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int arg2, long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(temp){
                check = true;
            }
            temp = true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            check = false;
        }
});

button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            if(check){

                //perform when user select spinner item             
            }else{

                //put Dialog for alert please select spinner item 

            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Hi Sandip, I used code provided by u..but even if I am not clicking on spinner, flag value is coming as true.

Comment: @Waugh please check new code in which i add one new flag., and it is required. so, put that and try.

Answer (score 0):

Call your `Intent` for the next `Activity` in the `Click Listener` of that spinner

Answer (score 0):

Create one boolean global variable like..

```
 boolean isSelect = false;
```

Now when user select value from spinner then make it `isSelect = false`. And when user click on NEXT button check condition for `isSelect` is true or false.

That's it.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the selected item value by using the following method.

```
         spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {    
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int arg2, long arg3) {
                if (spinner.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("YourValue")) {
                    Intent yourIntent = new Intent(this,YourClassName.class);
                    startActivity(yourIntent);
                }
            }    
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I added an extra item on first position of the list

1."Select Something"
2."Go next"
3."Go Previous"
5....
6..

then in use

```
String item=spinnerObject.getSelectedItem ();
    now check if("Select Something".equels(item)){
show some dialog to select anything from spinner
    }else{
send it to next screen
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a new Spinner class encapsulating the above mentioned principles. But even then you have to make sure to call the correct method and not `setSelection`

Same thing in a [gist](https://gist.github.com/vedant1811/d66fb759464bbe5c30e6)

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;

/**
 * Used this to differentiate between user selected and prorammatically selected
 * Call {@link Spinner#programmaticallySetPosition} to use this feature.
 * Created by vedant on 6/1/15.
 */
public class Spinner extends android.widget.Spinner implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

    OnItemSelectedListener mListener;

    /**
     * used to ascertain whether the user selected an item on spinner (and not programmatically)
     */
    private boolean mUserActionOnSpinner = true;

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        if (mListener != null) {

            mListener.onItemSelected(parent, view, position, id, mUserActionOnSpinner);
        }
        // reset variable, so that it will always be true unless tampered with
        mUserActionOnSpinner = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        if (mListener != null)
            mListener.onNothingSelected(parent);
    }

    public interface OnItemSelectedListener {
        /**
         * <p>Callback method to be invoked when an item in this view has been
         * selected. This callback is invoked only when the newly selected
         * position is different from the previously selected position or if
         * there was no selected item.</p>
         *
         * Impelmenters can call getItemAtPosition(position) if they need to access the
         * data associated with the selected item.
         *
         * @param parent The AdapterView where the selection happened
         * @param view The view within the AdapterView that was clicked
         * @param position The position of the view in the adapter
         * @param id The row id of the item that is selected
         */
        void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id, boolean userSelected);

        /**
         * Callback method to be invoked when the selection disappears from this
         * view. The selection can disappear for instance when touch is activated
         * or when the adapter becomes empty.
         *
         * @param parent The AdapterView that now contains no selected item.
         */
        void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent);
    }

    public void programmaticallySetPosition(int pos, boolean animate) {
        mUserActionOnSpinner = false;
        setSelection(pos, animate);
    }

    public void setOnItemSelectedListener (OnItemSelectedListener listener) {
        mListener = listener;
    }

    public Spinner(Context context) {
        super(context);
        super.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    }

    public Spinner(Context context, int mode) {
        super(context, mode);
        super.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    }

    public Spinner(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        super.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    }

    public Spinner(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        super.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    }

    public Spinner(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle, int mode) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle, mode);
        super.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    }
}
```